Can't click on the Reddit login button using Selenium
I'm trying to click on the loging button using Selenium, but it's not working somehow. I checked other repos and also previous threads but cannot find the solution. Here is my code:
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def interact(self, selector: str, text: str=None, wait=2, by=By.CSS_SELECTOR):
        element = self.driver.find_element(by=by, value=selector)
        if text is None:
            element.click()
        else:
            element.send_keys(text)
        time.sleep(wait)


class RedditBot(Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/login/")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rb = RedditBot()
    rb.interact("input[id='login-username']", text="Brave_Primary1797")
    rb.interact("input[id='login-password']", text="EcOjllIrz3M87q9S08M")
    rb.interact("#login > auth-flow-modal > div.w-100 > faceplate-tracker > button") # this line errors



what meas "not working"? Do you get error message when you run code in console? If you get error then show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. We can't see your computer and we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question (not in comments)

element is in shadow-root which is in another shadow-root,etc. It may need something like find_element('shreddit-async-loader').shadow_root.find_element('auth-flow-login').shadow_root.....

Is the issue that the program cant find the button or that its throwing an error?

Problem is because it uses shadow-root to make some elements protected against accidental changes by other elements. It allows to make templates and slots - and web developer may have simpler work.
But it makes problem to access these elements during web scraping.
You have to find out which elements use shadow-root (you can see it in HTML in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox) and use find_element(...).shadow_root.find_element(...) to get elements inside shadow-root.
I found all elements with shadow-root in DevTools and  I started checking which one needs to use .shadow_root - so finally I created something like this to test it manually:
(a it works for me)
def get_item(driver, selector, shadow=True):
    print('[DEBUG] ##### selector:', selector, shadow)
    
    item = driver.find_element(*selector)
    
    for child in item.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '*'):
        print(f'[DEBUG] child: <{child.tag_name}>')
        
    if shadow:
        print('[DEBUG] !!! getting shadow root')
        item = item.shadow_root
        
    return item

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        rb = RedditBot()
        time.sleep(2)
        
        rb.interact("input[id='login-username']", text="Brave_Primary1797")
        rb.interact("input[id='login-password']", text="EcOjllIrz3M87q9S08M")
        time.sleep(1)
        
        #rb.interact("#login > auth-flow-modal > div.w-100 > faceplate-tracker > button") # this line errors
        item = rb.driver        
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-overlay-display'))
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-signup-drawer'))
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-drawer'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-async-loader'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-slotter'))
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-async-loader'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'auth-flow-login'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'faceplate-tabpanel'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'faceplate-form'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'auth-flow-modal'), False)
#        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.w-100'), False)   # it finds different element
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[slot]'), False)  # OK
#        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[slot="primaryButton"]'), False)  # OK
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'faceplate-tracker'), False)
        item = item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button')
        item.click()        
            
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Exception", ex)            

Because in function get_item() I display children so I could see that I can reduce it to
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        rb = RedditBot()
        time.sleep(2)
        
        rb.interact("input[id='login-username']", text="Brave_Primary1797")
        rb.interact("input[id='login-password']", text="EcOjllIrz3M87q9S08M")
        time.sleep(1)
            
        (
            rb.driver        
            .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-overlay-display').shadow_root
            .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-signup-drawer').shadow_root
            .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-slotter').shadow_root
            .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button")
        ).click()
            
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Exception", ex)   


Full code which I was using:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def interact(self, selector: str, text: str=None, wait=2, by=By.CSS_SELECTOR):
        element = self.driver.find_element(by=by, value=selector)
        if text is None:
            element.click()
        else:
            element.send_keys(text)
        time.sleep(wait)


class RedditBot(Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/login/")


def get_item(driver, selector, shadow=True, attributes=['id', 'class']):
    print('[DEBUG] ##### selector:', selector, shadow)
    
    item = driver.find_element(*selector)
    
    for attr in attributes:
        print(f'[DEBUG] {attr}:', item.get_attribute(attr))
    
    for child in item.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '*'):
        print(f'[DEBUG] child: <{child.tag_name}>')
        
    if shadow:
        print('[DEBUG] !!! getting shadow root')
        item = item.shadow_root
        
    return item

    
def click_button_long_version():
        item = rb.driver        
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-overlay-display'))
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-signup-drawer'))
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-drawer'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-async-loader'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-slotter'))
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-async-loader'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'auth-flow-login'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'faceplate-tabpanel'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'faceplate-form'), False)
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'auth-flow-modal'), False)
#        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.w-100'), False)   # it finds different element
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[slot]'), False)  # OK
#        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[slot="primaryButton"]'), False)  # OK
        item = get_item(item, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'faceplate-tracker'), False)
        item = item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button')
        item.click()
        
        
def click_button():
    item = (
        rb.driver        
        .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-overlay-display').shadow_root
        .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-signup-drawer').shadow_root
        .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'shreddit-slotter').shadow_root
        #.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login auth-flow-modal div.w-100 faceplate-tracker button")
        .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button")
        #.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login auth-flow-modal div[slot] faceplate-tracker button")
    )
    item.click()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        rb = RedditBot()
        time.sleep(2)
        
        rb.interact("input[id='login-username']", text="Brave_Primary1797")
        rb.interact("input[id='login-password']", text="EcOjllIrz3M87q9S08M")
        time.sleep(1)
        
        #rb.interact("#login > auth-flow-modal > div.w-100 > faceplate-tracker > button") # this line errors
        click_button_long_version()
        #click_button()
            
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Exception", ex)            

    input("Press ENTER to exit")

